# CSS Flex columns layout with overflow

Tags: css, flexbox

Using pure CSS, is it possible to make the data flow in columns (like `flex-direction: column`) and also overflow the entire column layout? Like here:

[image: scaling of columns]

Examples seem to focus on specifying the number of columns upfront, or, using media queries to achieve this - but with the caveat that it hinges on *page width* and not on the size of the content (so you have to set the content to be e.g. 33% width when 3 columns).

Comment: I guess that "display: grid" would be better for your implementation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your best option is `columns`

```css
.container {
  background:lightblue;
  padding:10px;
  column-count:3;
  column-gap:10px;
}
@media (max-width:800px) {
  .container {column-count:2}
}
@media (max-width:400px) {
  .container {column-count:1}
}

.container div {
  padding:10px;
  margin:5px 0;
  display:inline-block;
  width:100%;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  background:grey;
}


/* irrelevant CSS*/
.container {
  counter-reset:num;
}
.container div:before {
  content:counter(num);
  counter-increment:num;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

Like below if you want to control the width:

```css
.container {
  background:lightblue;
  padding:10px;
  column-width:max(200px,100vw/4);
  column-gap:10px;
}


.container div {
  padding:10px;
  margin:5px 0;
  display:inline-block;
  width:100%;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  background:grey;
}


/* irrelevant CSS*/
.container {
  counter-reset:num;
}
.container div:before {
  content:counter(num);
  counter-increment:num;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

The `max(200px,100vw/4)` will get you a maximum number of columns equal to `3` and the 200px will control when we fall to `2` columns then `1`.